# MySql Access Denied when running python app [Ubuntu 1604/NGINX/uWSGI]

Tags: mysql, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a test python app on digitalocean for the first time. (**Ubuntu 16.04, uWSGI, NGINX**). I've added a user and granted all privileges (and triple checked privileges). When I try and run the app, none of my tables get created and when I check the mysql error logs I see: "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

The app itself runs fine without errors. It's just that none of my tables get created so when I enter a flask route that has a database query I get the 500 error

In my uWSGI, when defining database, I have the following:

```
ENVIRONMENT=DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:userpw@localhost:3306/databasename
```

command i ran to install mysql:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

What might I be missing? Its driving me crazy...

I followed this tutorial very carefully, but changed postgres to mysql:
https://github.com/CristianoYL/Tutorials/blob/master/How%20To%20Deploy%20Python%20App%20Using%20uWSGI%20And%20Nginx.md

Comment: are you using the dev server from flask or another one ?

Comment: Which package do you use to connect to MySQL?

Comment: @stamaimer I followed this tutorial, but changed postgres to mysql. I ssh into my digitalocean droplet and I can enter and even create tables in the specified database as 'user'... tutorial: https://github.com/CristianoYL/Tutorials/blob/master/How%20To%20Deploy%20Python%20App%20Using%20uWSGI%20And%20Nginx.md

Answer (score 0):

No mention so far, but how about `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`?

I'm also assuming there is no password. Password "NO" (as in none provided). I would look at the users table to see if they are set or not.  It might be easier to test from the mysql cli vs. HTTP 500 errors :)

I tried this as a comment first, but it said I need 50 rep. I'll edit this post until I figure out a better way...

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: yeah, I forgot when I first set up privileges, but I caught it later and ran it after re-setting privileges :(. This is really driving me crazy now